# How to add text at the end of line

Tags: c, csv

for example I have test.txt with

```
test1
test2
```

at the end of each line I would like to add some text

my code is:

```
fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");

while ((ch=getc(fp)) != EOF)
    if (ch == '\n')
        fprintf(fp, "newText");
```

my output is:

```
test1
newText
```

The outcome should be:

```
test1newText
test2newText
```

Comment: I'm a little confused whether you want to append text to the end of the file or whether you want to append text to the end of each line in your file.

Comment: to the end of each line

Comment: Your logic is a bit off. You are grabbing the char checking if it is a newline and if it is, writing your new info.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not an easy way to do this with one file. You'll probably want to use two files. One you read from and one you write to.

Comment: I will try it now Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it with a single file.

Here is what you need to do:

- Open an auxiliary file for temporary output
- Read the actual file line by line
- For each line write the copy of the line into the auxiliary output
- After writing the line write the suffix that you would like to append
- Go to the next line until you process the whole file
- Once you finished processing the whole file, close both files, and move the auxiliary file in place of the original input.

> How to avoid a new line?, I successfully copy [the text] but when I try to add some text at the end of each line, it starts from new line

This is because you include the end-of-line character in your copied text.

If you read character-by-character, do not copy `'\n'`s when you see them; if you read with `fgets`, check the last character, and skip it if it happens to be `'\n'` (`fgets` includes it in its return value).

Comment: I will try it now
Thanks

Comment: How to avoid a new line?, I success to copy
but when try to add some text at the end of each line, it starts from new line

Answer (score 2):

You can’t read from your output file like that.  It *is* possible to open a file for reading and writing, but it’s an advanced topic and isn’t really appropriate for text files.

The normal approach is to write to another file, and then replace the original if desired.  Note that you’ll have to emit all the characters you read *and* your extra text.

If this is the whole function of the program, consider making it a filter (by using the standard streams); this is what’s expected by experienced users and saves some error checking.

Answer (score 1):

eventually, I have succeed

```
if (!strcmp(fileName, SWM_DEBUG))
    {
        fp = fopen(fileName, "r");  
        fpOut = fopen("tmp.txt", "w");  

        while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            if (ch == '\n')
                fprintf(fpOut, "TEST");

            fputc(ch, fpOut);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your support ☺

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the fopen call to read from the file and use the fputc function to re-output the character you read, like this:

```
fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

while ((ch=fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
  if (ch == '\n') {
    fprintf(fp, "newText");
  }

  fputc(ch, fp);
}

fprintf(fp, "newText");
```

As pointed out elsewhere, you can't simultaneously read and write a file in the way you were trying to do, so i've changed it to read from stdin to illustrate the code